# Displaying a scientific notation double in a more readable format

Tags: c#, string-formatting, scientific-notation

I am reading in a value from a PLC via a third party library, however when saved as a double the value appears to be in scientific notation.

The value in the PLC is `1.234` however, when debugging the application, the value being stored in the double is `5.27326315571927E-315`

I am displaying this in a label, however I want to display it as `1.234` rather an as scientific notation.

How can I convert this?

Comment: FYI: `5.27326315571927E-315` != `1.234` . It is `~0`

Comment: I guess you need to show code but it sounds like you are puttin a float into a double or something along those lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a wild guess, I think you should read 4 bytes(float) from your library not double(8 bytes).

Since `5.27326315571927E-315` is *almost* zero.

```
double d = 5.27326315571927E-315;
byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(d);
float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(new byte[] { b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3] }, 0);
```

f is `1.2345` now

Comment: Interesting! I changed it to convert the value to a float, and I get the value 1.234 now. The sample code they provided states to convert to a double, and I have done this on a previous project and it worked fine... but not this time! Thanks!